# How do I replace onclick with a better alternative in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I wrote the following code and it works, but people are telling me not to use the onclick. How do I implement an alternative in a case like this? I'm replacing the "hidden" class with the "block" class, and vice versa. Would I be wrong to use this in production, or is there a better alternative as people have mentioned to me.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("menu");
  if (element.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    element.classList.replace("hidden", "block");
  } else if (element.classList.contains("block")) {
    element.classList.replace("block", "hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">
        <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
      </button>

<div id="menu" class="hidden">
  <p>I'm no longer hidden.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with inline click attributes is that their scoping rules are [very strange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) and unintuitive, and they require global pollution. Select the element using Javascript and use `addEventListener` instead.

You can also use `classList.toggle` instead of alternating between two different classes; the `.block` class isn't useful because a `<div>`'s ordinary `display` is *already* `block`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
  </button>

<div id="menu" class="hidden">
  <p>I'm no longer hidden.</p>
</div>
```

If you have multiple buttons and can't easily target the one you want to attach the listener to, then give it a class so you can target it with `querySelector`:

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
  </button>

<div id="menu" class="hidden">
  <p>I'm no longer hidden.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. One question though: document.querySelector('button')..., will this not trigger the toggle if I had other buttons on the page as well? Is there a way to querySelector() by id, or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: That's why I said *If you have multiple buttons and can't easily target the one you want to attach the listener to, then give it a class so you can target it with `querySelector`* - see the second snippet, give the button a class.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: document.querySelector('#menu-icon').addEventListener... seems to work as well. Is it ok/best practice to use querySelector with an id (instead of class) as well?

Comment: I prefer to avoid IDs because elements with IDs create properties on the global object, which results in unnecessary global pollution, and can occasionally result in confusing bugs, so I prefer classes instead

Answer (score 2):

See this answer on [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871830/11700321).

Whereby [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is discussed in this fashion:

> - The advantages are behaviour (Javascript) is separated from presentation (HTML)
> - no mixing of languages
> - you're using a javascript framework like jQuery that can handle most cross-browser issues for you
> - You can add behaviour to a lot of HTML elements at once without code duplication

The good news is that you don't need to do much to retrofit your code, you just need to:

1. Give your button a unique identifier (`id`)
2. Listen to the `click` event associated with that unique `id`
3. Run `myFunction` when this is clicked

Here is your code but retrofitted:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style>
      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }

      .block {
        display: block;
      }

      .icon {
        fill: currentColor;
        height: 24px;
        width: 24px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="btnHideShow">
      <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <title>Menu</title>
        <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
      </svg>
    </button>

    <div id="menu" class="hidden">
      <p>I'm no longer hidden.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementById("menu");
        if (element.classList.contains("hidden")) {
          element.classList.replace("hidden", "block");
        } else if (element.classList.contains("block")) {
          element.classList.replace("block", "hidden");
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("btnHideShow").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k37ndsh2/1/) to view as well.

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks. It's taking me a while to work through learning the basics. I just want to make sure I'm generally following best practices as I learn.